# How i can use multiple forms in loop at once

Tags: python, flask

I have problem with using multiple forms at once, tried with loop count in name but when i check correct options and then submit I get this error:

> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Code:

```
 {%for tournament in tournament_query%}
  <div class="body-main">
    <div class ="body-select">
      <form action="", method="POST">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="{{tournament.player_one}}"> {{tournament.player_one}}<br>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class ="body-selected">
    <form action="", method="POST">
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="{{tournament.player_two}}"> {{tournament.player_two}}<br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
  </div>
  {%endfor%}
```

my flask route =

```
@app.route("/news", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def news():
     tournament_query = Walka.query.join(Walka.Tournament).filter_by(name = 'Das').all()
     if request.method == "POST":
         option = request.form['options']
         return option 
     return render_template("news.html", tournament_query = tournament_query)
```

I want to get value from every one but I don't know how I can acquire it

Comment: Why don't you put player_one and player_two in 1 form?

Comment: Yea i just fixed that